# What are the general rules for determine on which two ends of a bar magnetic are its poles located?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I am wondering. Maybe somebody be nice enough to put a explanation that doesn't involve too much math.

I did notice that for bar magnets, their poles are not always on the two ends separated by the farthest distance.

Comment: Are you talking about the [Gilbert Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets#Gilbert_Model) and how to apply it?

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance, I have to read it, b/c I have absolutely no idea what it is.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you're talking about the [Gilbert Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets#Gilbert_Model) and how to apply it.

This is simply a phenomenological model that works out magnetostatic fields by putting sheets of magnetic monopoles near the ends of bar magnets: the field at a distance from the magnet is calculated by summing up all the forces owing to the monopoles worked out using an inverse square law. In effect, it is the magnetic analogue of an electrical capacitor.

What's the general rule for where your put the charges? Well here it is in is most general form: Near the ends of a bar magnet! The model is unphysical (there are no magnetic monopoles in the magnet). You find the locations half-experimentally: you simply tune your model to match reality for magnets of various shapes. This method is used a great deal in industry by magnet manufacturers to describe their wares. Often sheets of charge on the pole faces works well.

Some softwares use a uniform distribution of magnetic dipoles throughout the material. this model is much more physical and is the method used, for example, by [Finite Element Magnetics (FEMM)](http://www.femm.info/wiki/HomePage) which is popular freeware. I would recommend something like this if you are looking to model magnets: I used it many years ago to model the effects of small and irregular magnets with much more success than the Gilbert model.